# Psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: azure, docker-compose, odoo, azure-container-instances

I tried setting up Odoo and Postgres containers in azure using docker-compose, when running them I have an issue with the server closing the connection,

**That's what I get from the log at the start of the Postgres container:**

> The files belonging to this database system will be owned by the user "postgres".
> This user must also own the server process.
>
> The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
> The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
> The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
>
> Data page checksums are disabled.
>
> fixing permissions on existing directory /tmp ... ok
> creating subdirectories ... ok
> selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
> selecting default max_connections ... 100
> selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
> selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
> creating configuration files ... ok
> running bootstrap script ... ok
> performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
> syncing data to disk ... ok
>
> Success. You can now start the database server using:
>
> ```
> pg_ctl -D /tmp -l logfile start
> ```
>
> initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
> You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
> --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
> waiting for server to start....2022-10-17 14:27:53.717 UTC [758] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.8 (Debian 13.8-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
> 2022-10-17 14:27:53.735 UTC [758] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
> 2022-10-17 14:27:53.761 UTC [759] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-10-17 14:27:46 UTC
> 2022-10-17 14:27:53.774 UTC [758] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
> done
> server started
>
> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
>
> waiting for server to shut down...2022-10-17 14:27:53.985 UTC [758] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
> .2022-10-17 14:27:53.999 UTC [758] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
> 2022-10-17 14:27:54.006 UTC [758] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 765) exited with exit code 1
> 2022-10-17 14:27:54.007 UTC [760] LOG:  shutting down
> 2022-10-17 14:27:54.090 UTC [758] LOG:  database system is shut down
> done
> server stopped
>
> PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
>
> 2022-10-17 14:27:54.241 UTC [696] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.8 (Debian 13.8-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
> 2022-10-17 14:27:54.242 UTC [696] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
> 2022-10-17 14:27:54.242 UTC [696] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
> 2022-10-17 14:27:54.267 UTC [696] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
> 2022-10-17 14:27:54.307 UTC [770] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-10-17 14:27:54 UTC
> 2022-10-17 14:27:54.317 UTC [696] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

**Then that is the resulting logs from the Odoo container :**

> 2022-10-17 14:27:02,735 445 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 15.0-20221012
> 2022-10-17 14:27:02,735 445 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at
> /etc/odoo/odoo.conf  2022-10-17 14:27:02,735 445 INFO ? odoo: addons
> paths: ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons',
> '/var/lib/odoo/addons/15.0', '/mnt/extra-addons']  2022-10-17
> 14:27:02,735 445 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@db:5432  2022-10-17
> 14:27:02,960 445 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report:
> Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
> 2022-10-17 14:27:03,367 445 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service
> (werkzeug) running on localhost:8069  Exception in thread
> odoo.service.cron.cron0: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 445, in
> cron_thread
> pg_conn.poll() psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 473, in
> target
> self.cron_thread(i)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 457, in
> cron_thread
> thread.start_time = None   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 162, in **exit**
> self.close()   File "", line 2, in close   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 90, in check
> return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 379, in close
> return self._close(False)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 405, in _close
> self.rollback()   File "", line 2, in rollback   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 90, in
> check
> return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 484, in rollback
> result = self._cnx.rollback() psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed Exception in thread odoo.service.cron.cron1: Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 445, in
> cron_thread
> pg_conn.poll() psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 473, in
> target
> self.cron_thread(i)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 457, in
> cron_thread
> thread.start_time = None   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 162, in **exit**
> self.close()   File "", line 2, in close   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 90, in check
> return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 379, in close
> return self._close(False)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 405, in _close
> self.rollback()   File "", line 2, in rollback   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 90, in
> check
> return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 484, in rollback
> result = self._cnx.rollback() psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
>
> When I check the postgres logs again cause the connection was open the
> 1st time, i get this from it (after restart) :
>
> > The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
> > This user must also own the server process.
> >
> > The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
> > The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
> > The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
> >
> > Data page checksums are disabled.
> >
> > fixing permissions on existing directory /tmp ... ok
> > creating subdirectories ... ok
> > selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
> > selecting default max_connections ... 100
> > selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
> > selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
> > creating configuration files ... ok
> > running bootstrap script ... ok
> > performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok

**My docker-compose.yml :**

```
version: '3.2'

services:
   db:
     image: registryodoo.azurecr.io/samples/postgres:13
     volumes:
       - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
     deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
     ports:
      - "5432:5432"
     environment:
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: odoo
       POSTGRES_DB: postgres
       POSTGRES_USER: odoo
       PGDATA: /tmp
     healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U odoo"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

   odoocontainer:
     depends_on:
       db:
        condition: service_healthy
     image: registryodoo.azurecr.io/samples/odoo:latest
     volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/odoo
      - extra-addons:/mnt/extra-addons
     ports:
       - 8069:8069
     deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
     environment:
       HOST: db
       USER: odoo
       PASSWORD: odoo
volumes:
  data:   
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: datafileshare
      storage_account_name: odooaccount1
  db:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: dbfileshare
      storage_account_name: odooaccount1

  extra-addons:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: odoofileshare
      storage_account_name: odooaccount1
```

Can't figure what's the origin issue and how to solve it